# conditional associated in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know it is a basic logic question but I always wanted to get rid of the doubt and I can not find an explanation.

I understand that in the propositional logic I can transform a conditional in these three different ways

$P \Rightarrow  Q :$

$Q \Rightarrow P$

$\neg P \Rightarrow  \neg Q$

$\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P$

I do not understand how they can be "replaced" if their truth tables are not equivalent.
Can I transform $P \Rightarrow Q$ into any of them?

I can not find the explanation of how it can happen.

Thanks.

Comment: pst: Only *one* of the three is an equivalent statement.

Comment: See [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P\to Q$ is equivalent to its contraposition: $\lnot Q\to \lnot P$.   If indeed $P$ implies $Q$, but $Q$ is false, then $P$ cannot be true.   So $P\to Q$ entails $\lnot Q\to \lnot P$.   Also *vice versa* (in classical logic).   Thus they are syntactically equivalent.   You may also show semantic equivalence by truth tables.

$Q\to P$ is the *converse* of $P\to Q$.   It is not logically equivalent to $P\to Q$ .

NB: $Q\to P$  is, of course, equivalent to *its* contraposition, $\lnot P\to \lnot Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Relative to $P \to Q$:

$Q \to P$ is its [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic))

$\neg P \to \neg Q$ is its [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_(logic))

$\neg Q \to \neg P$ is its [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)